# Webview Navigation events not firing on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi i have using following code working fine android but not get response from iOS in xamarin forms

```
 web_view_login.Source = "https://aix.takoma.fr/takoma/app-lo/api/ihm/sign-in?client_id=h0YhUHzaWPvhJuk8euOcAco8Fc6yRBXM&response_type=token&redirect_uri=anton::authz";


 public async void WebViewnavigated(WebNavigatedEventArgs args, NavigationEventArgs e, string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(web_view_login.Source);
            var uri = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(obj)["Url"];


            var access_token = uri.ToString();

            if (access_token.Contains("access_token"))
            {
                var accesstoken_ = uri.ToString().Split(new char[] { '?', '&', '{', '}', '=' })[2];
                var token_type = uri.ToString().Split(new char[] { '?', '&', '{', '}', '=' })[4];
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Home());
                //await Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

webview login button click after i'm still getting pass url value in iOS but android login button click after get as accesstoken value.

what did i'm wrong. anyone know then help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <WebView x:Name="webAccess" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

Declared below the line in the constructor it's working for me

```
 webAccess.Navigated += WebNavigated;
```

**Event**

```
  async void WebNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e){

    }
```

Comment: Still like previous of it login button click after pass url value only get not get accesstoken after login

Comment: hi anyother sol?